# Angular Subcomponents

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I was developing an application and  I was hesitant on a few issues. I send the data I pulled from the api in the main component to the subcomponents. In other words, I provide the data of my 3 components with a single api request. Is it more correct to do this this way, or should each component pull its own data separately from the api? (In this case, there will be a total of 3 network requests on my page)

Another question is, when the user updates the data on any component, is it necessary to get request the api again?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycIN9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wte5W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, you can ask yourself the following question: Should the subcomponent be able to live by itself? Meaning is there a case where it is used independently of the other subcomponents.
If the answer is yes it should probably retrieve its own data.

But more generally it is a good idea to use a service that retrieves and stores the data and all the components can get their data from there.

On the second question, it is impossible to answer without more context. What kind of data is retrieved from the API and what is updated?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, components are not used alone, they will be used together with certain components. Let me explain my other question with an example. For example, I updated the 'name' and  'about' in the component and 200 status code returned from the api. After this process, do I need to pull the related data from the api again with the get request?

Comment: @BerkanÇep If you send a post request that updates the persistent storage it is a good practice to return the updated project with the 200 status code and then update it in the component.